# Flow not Triggering as expected

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, create-records

Flow should create a "move" when a repair record is created or updated with the repair vendor as "Rau Warehouse". The repair record I am using meets that criteria, but I have not had success triggering the flow. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Hey Alex! Are you modifying the Repair records Vendor field from another value to Rau Warehouse when testing?

Comment: Have you tried testing and debugging your flow? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/flow-testing-and-distribution/make-sure-your-flow-works

Comment: @RyanSherry yes, I have tried creating a new repair as well as updating the repair vendor from another vendor to Rau Warehouse on an existing repair record, but neither triggered the creation of a move record. When I was creating the flow originally on the Create action, there is a Global variable that was already created called "Triggering Repair__c". I assume that this is something Salesforce created to reference the repair record from earlier in my flow, but that could be a wrong assumption?

Comment: @identigral yes, I tried both debug and testing, but was not able to trigger using a record that should meet the trigger criteria. When I was creating the flow originally on the Create action, there is a Global variable that was already created called "Triggering Repair__c". I assume that this is something Salesforce created to reference the repair record from earlier in my flow, but that could be a wrong assumption?

Comment: When you debug the flow does it say not - triggered?

Comment: @RyanSherry unfortunately yes, the record I am using has the criteria to trigger the flow, but it is not triggering when running as created or updated.

Comment: I see your using a Contains function - could you try setting it = to an exact value. Just to prove that it works on specific vendor.

Comment: What is the data type of `Vendor__c` - lookup, text, or picklist?

Comment: Hi @DavidCheng, it is a lookup

Comment: Hi @RyanSherry, I updated to the = exact value and am still not triggering